# Getting "Could not parse launch error at line X"

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

My Java Launch is not working any more, it says

```
Could not parse launch error at line 7" at [ashishranjan.in](http://www.ashishranjan.in)
```

Line 7 is actually in my sub domain which is

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"; async defer></script>
```

It used to work properly, but after making a sub-domain in Godaddy, it stopped working. The sub domain has been created for mobile devices.
For mobile I used "m" named sub folder and an index.php page inside it.

Comment: The line 7 is actually in my sub domain which is "<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" async defer></script>"

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: @AndrewThompson... thanks a lot... actually I had created one sub-domain in godaddy "m.ashishranjan.in" (ashishranjan.in automatically redirects to mobile site ) for my mobile site and the "index.php" in that "m" sub folder was interfering in the working of my JWS jnlp file. I removed that sub-domain and now it is working perfectly fine. Now, I have to look something for my mobile site, again. Any help for my mobile site ??? Anyway, thanks for the help and thanks for JaNeLa... I appreciate your help... see u... take care

Comment: @AndrewThompson... I checked my jnlp with janela.jar... it says that there is some problem with my script tag and property "async", the way I wrote it... This helped me a lot and thanks a lot... you made my day... love you

Comment: Glad it helped solve the problem.  :)